Sort Parameter affects amount hits returned by MS Graph Search API
The MS Graph Search API provides not all Hits if a sorting Parameter is set:
{    
   "requests":[
  {
     "trimDuplicates":true,
     "sortProperties":[
        {
           "isDescending":"true",
           "name":"name"
        }
     ],
     "fields":[
        "id",
        "name"
     ],
     "size":50,
     "from":0,
     "query":{
        "querString":"documentlink:\"https://[REMOVED].sharepoint.com/sites/[REMOVED]/Accounts/Mixed Folder/*\" AND IsContainer=false"
     },
     "entityTypes":[
        "driveItem"
     ]
  }
]
}

This leads to following result:
{
"value": [
    {
        "searchTerms": [],
        "hitsContainers": [
            {
                "hits": [
                    [HITS REMOVED]
                ],
                "total": 14,
                "moreResultsAvailable": false
            }
        ]
    }
],
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.searchResponse)
}

The exactly same Query but without a sorting parameter:
{
  "requests":[
  {
     "trimDuplicates":true,
     "fields":[
        "id",
        "name"
     ],
     "size":50,
     "from":0,
     "query":{
        "queryString":"documentlink:\"https://[REMOVED].sharepoint.com/sites/[REMOVED]/Accounts/Mixed Folder/*\" AND IsContainer=false"
     },
     "entityTypes":[
        "driveItem"
     ]
    }
  ]
}

Leads to 23 Results:
{
  "value": [
    {
        "searchTerms": [],
        "hitsContainers": [
            {
                "hits": [
                    [HITS REMOVED]
                ],
                "total": 23,
                "moreResultsAvailable": false
            }
        ]
    }
],
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.searchResponse)"
}

What is happening? Is this API broken? Why is the Sorting Paramet breaking the expected result of 23 Items.
